# react 17.0.1 object.entries create dynamic table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the object:

```
[
{
    "Sno": "1",
    "First Name": "name",
    "Last Name": "las2t name",
    "Email": "test@gmail.com",
    "Amount": "2000"
},
{
    "Sno": "2",
    "First Name": "first name",
    "Last Name": "last name",
    "Email": "test2@gmail.com",
    "Amount": "2000"
}
]
```

Here is my code to render it in the table format

```
{Object.entries(schedule).map(([key,value]) => {
    return(
         <Table>
             <thead style={{ background: '#8b8498' }}>
                 <tr>
                     <th>{key}</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>{key[value]}</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </Table>
      )
})}
```

How to render the array with key value pairs dynamically ???

Comment: You have an array there. So, I don't see how you can use Object.entries on an array as there are no key value pairs in an array

Comment: @Near Object.entries will work on an array, it will return `key` = index and `value` = entry.

Comment: What do you want the resulting table to look like?

Comment: an table with <thead><tr><th>Sno</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr></thead> and so on for the tbody as well

Comment: @Nick My bad. I think I didn't frame my sentence properly. I don't see how using Object.entries on this array will result in putting the actual key value pairs in their respective elements in the table

Comment: @Near That I agree with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.entries(schedule).map(([key,value])...` is, admittedly, an unorthodox way of iterating through a basic array of objects, but since that's how you started it and did not ask for a different approach, here is how I would render your table:

```
      <table>
        <thead style={{ background: "#8b8498" }}>
          <tr>
            {Object.keys(schedule[0]).map((j, i) => (
              <td key={i}>{j}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Object.entries(schedule).map(([key, value]) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                {Object.values(value).map((j, i) => (
                  <td key={i}>{j}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-pine-nhj4o?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what would be the best approach for this ?

Comment: @deepakmurthy I have updated the Sandbox with a second table showing the same data but using the most common (and more efficient) way to display it.

Comment: i get this error - Cannot convert undefined or null to object
I am using useEffect

Comment: @deepakmurthy It's probably an unrelated error that has to do with trying to render before the data is actually loaded. Create another question with the full code and give me a link to it here, I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the headers separately and render each item in a row with the help of map.

```js
const myArray = [
{
    "Sno": "1",
    "First Name": "name",
    "Last Name": "las2t name",
    "Email": "test@gmail.com",
    "Amount": "2000"
},
{
    "Sno": "2",
    "First Name": "first name",
    "Last Name": "last name",
    "Email": "test2@gmail.com",
    "Amount": "2000"
}
]

const headers = Object.keys(myArray[0]);

        return (
            <Table>
                <thead style={{ background: '#8b8498' }}>
                    <tr>
                        {headers.map((key) => (
                            <th>{key}</th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    {myArray.map((item) => {
                        <tr>
                            <td>{item['Sno']}</td>
                            <td>{item['First Name']}</td>
                            <td>{item['Last Name']}</td>
                            <td>{item['Email']}</td>
                            <td>{item['Amount']}</td>
                        </tr>
                    })}
                 </tbody>
             </Table>
         )
```

other way to render using key.

```
const headers = Object.keys(myArray[0]);

    return (
        <Table>
            <thead style={{ background: '#8b8498' }}>
                <tr>
                    {headers.map((key) => (
                        <th>{key}</th>
                    ))}
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                {myArray.map((item) => {
                    <tr>
                        {headers.map((key) => (
                            <td>{item[key]}</td>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                })}
             </tbody>
         </Table>
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, assuming that every object in the array has the same keys, where schedule is the array from your exmaple:

```js
const headKeys = Object.keys(schedule[0]);

return (
  <Table>
    <thead style={{ background: '#8b8498' }}>
      <tr>
        {headKeys.map((key, index) => {
          return <th key={index}>{key}</th>;
        })}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {schedule.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <tr>
            {headKeys.map((key, index) => {
              return <td key={index}>{item[key]}</td>;
            })}
          </tr>
        );
      })}
      <tr>
        <td>{item[value]}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </Table>
);
```